# How to change UIView background image based on time of day (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let homepageDay = UIImage(cgImage:  "Homepage Day" as! CGImage)
    let homepageNight = UIImage(cgImage: "Homepage Night" as! CGImage)
    let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

    switch hour
    {
         // hours 1 to 6
    case 1...6: homepageDay. = UIImage
        //self.backgroundImage = homepageNight
                break
         // hours 7 to 18
```

Want to change background image depending on time of day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get hours of current date in a variable like:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
```

> Now pass this to your switch statement and change the image.

Your Swift Statement will be like this (Change images as per your need):

```
switch hour {
    case 1...6: 
        yourImageView.image = homepageNight
    case 7...18: 
        yourImageView.image = homepageNight
    default:
        yourImageView.image = homepageNight
 }
```

If you have any doubts please comment.

Happy to help!

Comment: so would the switch statement be                                                                                  
  switch hour
    {
         // hours 1 to 6
    case 1...6: homepageDay.backgroundimage = UIImage

Comment: that helped but im getting an error message that value of type "viewController" has  no member "backgroundImage" ??

Comment: you need to replace self.backgroundImage with your imageView...that will solve your issue...

Comment: but you cannot assign a property to itself correct? so I couldnt replace self.backgroundImage with my imageView(homepageNight or homepageDay) with the @IBOutlet

Comment: Try: youImageView.image = homepageNight

Comment: nope, getting the cannot aassign value to to type UIImageView to type UIImage again. Code:

Comment: add .image with your UIImageView

Comment: is it fine now?

Comment: so would it be the same if I wanted my button to change along with the background?

Comment: switch hour {
        case 1...6, 19...23, 0:
            backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Homepage Night")
            rollImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Homepage Night Button - Roll")        // RollImageView is the button image

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the current hour and know if its AM or PM, you can use something like this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh a" // "a" prints "pm" or "am"
let hourString = formatter.string(from: Date()) // "12 AM"
```

So, after this you only need to apply your correct image bay the hour getting the string value.